# Looking for an examples of "request as a process" in erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erl

In [One major difference - ZeroMQ and Erlang](http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.com/2011/10/one-major-difference-zeromq-and-erlang.html) author mentions briefly "request as a process" idea. I'm new to Erlang and I'd like to see an example or an article how to do it.

Any resource or hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a newbie too but to me the idea seems simple. For each request, whatever it is, spawn a new process and let it handle the request. That is all. This guy talks about that too: http://vimeo.com/19806728

So my understanding is that when you receive a request, you spawn a process by calling `spawn(Module, Name, Args)`, or another variant of this function (see http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html) and pass the request data in the `Args` list. `Module` and `Name` identify a function that is executed when the process starts and that deals with the `Args`.

Comment: Hmmm what you are saying can be seen in a classic erlang example of tcp server. I still think I'm missing something evident. thank you

Comment: what do you think you are missing?

Comment: @akonsu Right on. For what it's worth, you almost always want to use `spawn_link/3` rather than `spawn/3`. It's a real shame when a worker process dies and you've no idea.